# Python textfile formatting

Tags: python

Here is the text file

```
apple1
apple2
apple3
date with apple
flower1
flower2
flower3
flower4
date with flower
dog1
dog2
date with dog
```

I need a python code that helps me turn the file into something like this

```
apple1|date with apple
apple2|date with apple
apple3|date with apple
flower1|date with flower
flower2|date with flower
flower3|date with flower
flower4|date with flower
dog1|date with dog
dog2|date with dog
```

it will probably need a nested loop, one that counts until line.startswith "date" then when it gets there it appends every line before it then the counter starts over while x is between range of 0 and total line count. Ideas?

Comment: What do you need help with, or are you just asking for someone to write the code for you? Is there a specific aspect of this problem that you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution requires a list that contains the things that do not start with date.

```
f = open('apple.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
things = []
printtofile = []
for i in lines:
    things.append(i)
    if i.startswith('date'):
        things.pop()
        for x in things:
            if i[:-1] == '\n':
                printtofile.append(x[:-1]+'|'+i[:-1])
            else: 
                printtofile.append(x[:-1]+'|'+i)
        things = []
print printtofile
writefile = open('file.txt', 'w')
writefile.writelines(printtofile)
writefile.close()
```

Hope it helps, Python 2.7

Comment: How could i edit this to remove the blank lines?

Comment: in the print statement just change the variable i for i[:-1] the same as i did in the x.

Comment: I just made the change.

Comment: for some reason on date with dog, it prints out date with do?

Comment: That is because there is no return in the last line. if you give enter then the last caracter would be the return instead of the g of dog.

Comment: how could i fix this?

Comment: Ok if you want to force it, I just made the edit.

Comment: Last thing i need to do is write this to a file instead of printing it in the terminal would you 
f.write(x[:-1]+'|'+i[:-1])?

Comment: Ehh, if you intent to program in python, I encourage you to start reading a book. I´ll make just this last edit, please close this question after the edit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about what you want, but I guess this is it:

```
lines = []
buffer = []
for line in f:
    if 'date with' in line:
        lines.extend(["%s|%s" % (x, line) for x in buffer])            
        buffer = []
    else: 
        buffer.append(line)

# print lines
for line in lines:
    print line

# or save in a file
with open('myfile', 'w'):
    for line in lines:
         f.write(line)
```

Comment: how do i print the output

Comment: lines = []
buffer = []
with open('C:/Users/dit3442/Desktop/smallfruit.txt') as infp:
    for line in infp:
        if 'date with' in line:
            lines.extend(["%s|%s" % (x, line) for x in buffer])            
        buffer = []
    else: 
        buffer.append(line)

Comment: I've updated my response, check it ;)

Comment: im getting no output
lines = []
buffer = []
with open('C:/Users/dit3442/Desktop/smallfruit.txt') as infp:
    for line in infp:
        if 'date with' in line:
            lines.extend(["%s|%s" % (x, line) for x in buffer])            
        buffer = []
    else: 
        buffer.append(line)

for line in lines:
    print line

Comment: Are you sure ? I'm getting the expected result with your file. Do you corretly read your initial file? Check its content (`f` in my script here)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an itertools approach:

```
from itertools import groupby, izip, product

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    grouped = groupby(fin, lambda L: not L.startswith('date'))
    lines = ([el.strip() for el in g] for k, g in grouped)
    paired = izip(*[lines]*2)
    for pair in paired:
        fout.writelines('|'.join(items) + '\n' for items in product(*pair))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got two solutions for you,

reading file from the end and collect the items as it flow, with simple logic:

```py
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
output=[]
for line in reversed(lines):
        if line.startswith("date with"): msg = line
        else: output.append("{0}|{1}".format(line[:-1], msg))
for line in reversed(output): print line
```

and in traditional way from the top of file line by line:

```py
granary = []
basket = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        basket.append(line)
        if line.startswith("date with"):
            granary += map(lambda x: "{0}|{1}".format(x[:-1], line), basket[:-1])
            del basket[:]
for item in granary: print item
```